# Can I Access an ADO .Net Data Service from Silverlight across domain with a proper crossdomain.xml file w/out relying on ADO .Net Silverlight Client?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services

If I create an ADO .Net Data Service, can I access it from Silverlight across domains as long as I don't use the ADO .Net Silverlight Client helpers and I have a proper crossdomain.xml file in place? (I would essentially just get the raw xml and parse it myself)

Asked another way, is it the ADO .Net Data Services Silverlight Client components that don't allow crossdomain calls, or is it the ADO .Net Data Service itself?

I assume it's the client components but would like some confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about using a Server-side proxy to make the Silverlight Client library with DataServices hosted on a different domain .
http://blogs.msdn.com/phaniraj/archive/2008/10/21/accessing-cross-domain-ado-net-data-services-from-the-silverlight-client-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I found it is as I suspected, the ADO .Net Data Services **Silverlight Client** limits the communication to calls that are from the same domain. (Not ADO .Net Data Services itself)

This apparently is going to be fixed in a future version of Silverlight.